# UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less than n_splits=2

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn, model, dataset

I have just started doing machine learning and wanted to try to do a very simple "stock prediction" script using sklearn, numpy, pandas, and matplotlib.  However I keep running into an issue when running my model (note: this is made in google.colab so I ran each part in different cells)

This is my dataset and libraries I am using for context

```
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

import numpy as np

import math

from matplotlib import pyplot


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

from sklearn.svm import SVC

import csv


names = ['Date','Val']

rows = [
    [1,264.91],
    [2,259],
    [3,255.41],
    [4,257.64],
    [5,264.28],
    [8,255.31],
    [9,265.74],
    [10,264.90],
    [11,273.88],
    [12,268.40],
    [15,273.75],
    [16,279.28],
    [17,284.01],
    [18,278.62],
    [19,290.11],
    [22,293.54],
    [23,290.63],
    [24,282.14],
    [25,278.74],
    [26,283.02],
    [29,290.82],
    [30,288],
    [31,294.53],
]

for row in rows:
    for r in row:
    if type(r) is float:
        i = row.index(r)
        r = int(r)
        row[i] = r

with open('stock.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerows(rows)

dataset = read_csv('stock.csv',names=names)
```

And then this

```
array = dataset.values
X = array[:,1:2]
y = array[:,1]
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, 
random_state=1)

models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', multi_class='ovr')))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC(gamma='auto')))
results = []
names = []
```

Then when I run this cell for my model

```
for name, model in models:
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, 
    scoring='accuracy')
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    print('%s: %f (%f)' % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()))
```

I get this long output

```
LR: 0.055556 (0.055556)
LDA: nan (nan)
KNN: 0.111111 (0.000000)
CART: 0.500000 (0.055556)
NB: 0.500000 (0.055556)
SVM: 0.500000 (0.055556)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:667:                 
UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less 
than n_splits=2.
% (min_groups, self.n_splits)), UserWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:667: 
UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less than 
n_splits=2.
% (min_groups, self.n_splits)), UserWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536:     
FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for 
these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
ValueError: The number of samples must be more than the number of classes.

FitFailedWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536: 
FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for 
these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
ValueError: Internal work array size computation failed: -10

FitFailedWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:667: 
UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less than 
n_splits=2.
% (min_groups, self.n_splits)), UserWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:667: 
UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less than 
n_splits=2.
% (min_groups, self.n_splits)), UserWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:667: 
UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less than 
n_splits=2.
% (min_groups, self.n_splits)), UserWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:667: 
UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less than 
n_splits=2.
% (min_groups, self.n_splits)), UserWarning)
```

I guess I am really confused about what members and classes are and don't know how to get y to have more members, at least that's what I think needs to be done.  Can someone please explain?

Comment: Have you double check about these errors: **The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less than `n_splits=2`.** and **The number of samples must be more than the number of classes.**?

Comment: Ohhhh, so does that mean I just need more data?

Comment: You shouldn't be using classifiers or stratified k-fold for this regression task.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).